# How to add new fields to the front of a message event in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to find a way on how I can add new fields to the beginning of a message in logstash.

Background: I am ingesting data in JSON format and adding new fields to the message using the mutate.add_field plugin.

However, I can't seem to find a way to define the position of this new field. The message is then outputted to a file as a string. From here, there are other processes that picks up this file and applies regex to pull the information it needs. To simplify the regex patterns, I am looking to put the key fields at the beginning of the message.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a new field with the order that you want and remove the other fields.

For example, if your document has the fields `fieldA` and `fieldB` and in your pipeline you add the fields `otherFieldC` and `otherFieldD` that you want to be in front of your message you should do something like this:

```
mutate {
  add_field =>  { 
      "all_fields" => "%{otherFieldC} %{otherFieldD} %{fieldA} %{fieldB}"
   }
   remove_field => ["fieldA","fieldB","otherFieldC","otherFieldD"]
}
```

Your output will be a unique field with the information of your original fields plus the ones that you added in the pipeline.